# Box Collider 2D overlapping in Unity

Tags: unity-game-engine, unity3d-2dtools

I have two GameObjects with a box collider. One is the player, moved with a fixed velocity towards the other. The collision stops the player (the Poo character ;D)

But they overlap, you can see it here:
[image]

I don't know why this is happening. Colliding with the top or bottom works just fine...The same effect happens from the left side. The green block has just a collider, no RigidBody.

Gif:
[image]

Another Gif, with MovePosition() ... Colliding fromt the top works, but "reentering" stops the character. Why?!:
[image]

3. GIF, moving up and down is okay, left and right at the top of the blocks slows him down. Weird...
   [image]

Movement Script:

```c#
public class PlayerController : MonoBehaviour
{
    public float Speed = 10f;

    private Rigidbody2D rb2D;

    private Vector2 DirectionLeft;
    private Vector2 DirectionRight;
    private Vector2 DirectionUp;
    private Vector2 DirectionDown;

    private Vector2 CurrentDirection;

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start()
    {
        rb2D = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();

        DirectionLeft = new Vector2(Speed*-1, 0);
        DirectionRight = new Vector2(Speed, 0);
        DirectionUp = new Vector2(0, Speed * -1);
        DirectionDown = new Vector2(0, Speed);

        CurrentDirection = DirectionLeft;
    }

    void SetAnimationDirection()
    {
        Vector3 scale = transform.localScale;

        if (CurrentDirection == DirectionLeft)
            scale.x = 1;
        else
            scale.x = -1;

        transform.localScale = scale;
    }

    void FixedUpdate()
    {
        float moveHorizontal = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal");
        float moveVertical = Input.GetAxis("Vertical");

        if (moveHorizontal > 0)
            CurrentDirection = DirectionRight;
        if (moveHorizontal < 0)
            CurrentDirection = DirectionLeft;
        if (moveVertical < 0)
            CurrentDirection = DirectionUp;
        if (moveVertical > 0)
            CurrentDirection = DirectionDown;

        Debug.Log(CurrentDirection);
        SetAnimationDirection();

        rb2D.velocity = CurrentDirection;
    }
```

Comment: Hi, the problem is because you are modifying the `transform.localScale` in the `SetAnimationDirection` function. This is being done every frame or physics frame. It would be good to only execute `transform.localScale = scale` When you change the move direction instead of doing it every time.....Don't you think so?

Comment: Hi thanks for checking :) It's working now :D But the character still gets stuck when moved like in the 3rd GIF. Do you have any idea why that happens?! (I mean colliding at the top, moving right, then back left => gets stuck at the edge). But thank you very much!!! :D

Comment: I will add a new question. This seems to be a regular 2D physics problem...just reproduced it with a minimal Unity 2D project...

Comment: I noticed this too. Change Box Colliders's **Edge Radius** to `0.09` The collider may now be bigger than the image which means you should decrease the size of the collider. The point of increasing **Edge Radius** to `0.09` is to give it round edge so that the stuck issue will be gone

Comment: Mhh okay. My sprites are 64x64 pixels. changing the edge radius makes the collider thicker. Now I have to find the perfect match for Size and Edge Radius. I'll open a new question for this...

Comment: This is why I said you have to resize the collider to match after changing the radius. *Go to Scene tab then resize each collider*. It is easy to do and resizing a collider will **not** resize the sprites.There is no need to open new question for this. Just Google how to resize a collider in Unity.

Comment: Didn't read your edit. Yeah I know that it won't resize the sprite. I guess 0.9 for the Edge and 0.8 for the size works good enough. Thank you very much for taking your time! :)

Comment: You are welcome. It doesn't have to be 0.9. Any number that will do it is fine. Happy coding!

Comment: Now that you have arrived at a solution to the problem, one of you (DoubleVoid or @Programmer) needs to post it in the answer box below. Answers do not belong in comments.

Comment: @DoubleVoid You can put what we discussed that worked for you as an answer. That's fine with me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution to the first problem (overlapping):

I used `transform.localScale = scale` to change the direction of the sprite on every `FixedUpdate()` and also forgot to update the factor of the scale, since I added a new extension, which resized my object by 1 more Unity unit.

The other problem (getting stuck at the edge) is solved adding setting the **Edge Radius** of the Collider 2D to something below `1.0f` (e.g `0.09f`) and also **resize the bounding box**. This will prevent the object from getting stuck at the edges, because the bounding box edges are now rounded.